# Is is possible to add member variables to objects at runtime in Actionscript 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an object of type sprite. I would like to add a new field in the sprite object without deriving the class. I'm not sure is possible.

I tried to do

```
 object.newField = 'value';
```

but it's not working.

I need it because the Api expect that field in the sprite class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible for objects of [dynamic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#dynamic) classes.

For example, Sprite is not a dynamic class, but MovieClip is. This will fail with "1119: Access of possibly undefined property newField through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite":

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.newField = 'value';
```

But this will work:

```
var m:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
m.newField = 'value';
```

Comment: Good to know. Dynamic classes are new to people coming to actionscript from other languages. I think this was the problem. I was using a sprite object(as parameter in my function) and it failed, then I switched to MC then it worked.